# DNN Created Theme Upload stuck after accepting license

Tags: installation, themes, dotnetnuke, skin

I created a theme and the screenshot of the files in the folder is as follows:
[image: Folder that contains my theme files]

My .dnn file is:

```
<dotnetnuke type="Package" version="5.0">
        <packages>
            <package name="mz.MyTheme" type="Skin" version="1.0.0">
                <friendlyName>My Sample Theme</friendlyName>
                <description>My Sample Theme is a demonstration module.</description>
                <iconFile />
                <owner>
                    <name>MyCompany or MyName</name>
                    <organization>MyCompany Corporation</organization>
                    <url>www.example.com</url>
                    <email>support@example.com</email>
                </owner> 
                 <license src="license.txt" />
                <releaseNotes src="releasenotes.txt" />
                <azureCompatible>true</azureCompatible>               
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency type="coreVersion">09.08.00</dependency>                
                </dependencies>   
                <components>             
                    <component type="Skin">
                        <skinFiles>
                            <basePath>portals\_default\skins\MyTheme</basePath>
                            <skinName>MyTheme</skinName>
                            <skinFile>
                                <!--<path></path>-->
                                <name>MyTheme.html</name>
                            </skinFile>
                            <skinFile>                               
                                <name>MyTheme.css</name>
                            </skinFile>
                            <skinFile>                             
                                <name>MyTheme.doctype.xml</name>
                            </skinFile>
                        </skinFiles>
                    </component>
                    <component type="ResourceFile">
                        <resourceFiles>
                            <basePath>portals\_default\skins\MyTheme</basePath>                            
                            <resourceFile>
                                <name>wwwroot.zip</name> 
                            </resourceFile>
                        </resourceFiles>
                    </component>
                </components>
            </package>
        </packages>
    </dotnetnuke>
```

the html file is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="wwwroot/css/bootstrap5-rtl.css" />
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="bg-warning" dir="rtl">
            Hello How are you
            <img src="wwwroot/images/gb.png" />
            <div id="ContentPane" runat="server">
               
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="wwwroot/js/bootstrap5.bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

but during upload and after accepting the license and clicking next, a progressbar appears at the top that never completes and a message shows about processing data, and the installation stops forever at this point, how to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Check both the admin logs and /portals/_default/logs to see if any details are reported.

Also compare files in the install zip file to seenif everything mentioned in the .DNN file actually is there.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know that a DNN skin file will work without an ASCX file.

I suggest download a basic skin zip file and compare it's contents to your zip file.

I have installed skins directly into the /portals/_default/skins folder so that is something to consider.

May i recommend Chris Hammond's tutorials? He sets you up with a project, lots of videos with instructions and actual DNN help. https://christoc.com/Tutorials/DNN9-Tutorials

Comment: I saw some zip packages including hammond's project template "..Install.zip" but I can't find any reason that my zip not working. I finally had to just modify xcillion theme css and ascx files. to have a new look for my site.